# How to implement "greater than" based on dimension value in MDX

Tags: ssas, mdx

I would like to query the total sales of each country with the GDP growth rate of more than 3. So far, I can display the sales information of each country like such:

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[Sales]} ON 0,
{[Dim Company Info].[LOC].ALLMEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [Database]
```

But then I am still blank on how to query all GDP growth rate of more than 3. I have searched SO and found filter to be the answer, however, I do not know where to include it in my code above. How do I go about this?

Edit: I have tried the followings, but I do not think that is what I am supposed to do:

```
WHERE ([Dim Company Info].[Gdp Growth].&[3] : [Dim Company Info].[Gdp Growth].&[3].LastChild)
```

and

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[SALES]} ON 0,
{FILTER([Dim Company Info].[LOC].MEMBERS, [Dim Company Info].[Gdp Growth] > 3)} ON 1
FROM [766 Database]
```

and

```
SELECT 
{[Measures].[SALES]} ON COLUMNS,
{[Dim Company Info].[LOC].MEMBERS} ON ROWS
FROM [766 Database]
WHERE FILTER([Dim Company Info].[Gdp Growth], [Dim Company Info].[Gdp Growth] > 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use your below expression when the dimension members are numericly arranged

> WHERE ([Dim Company Info].[Gdp Growth].&[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVn1o.jpg) : [Dim Company Info].[Gdp
> Growth].&[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVn1o.jpg).LastChild)
> with a slight correction

```
WHERE ([Dim Company Info].[Gdp Growth].&[3] : [Dim Company Info].[Gdp Growth].[Gdp Growth].LastChild)
```

However if that is not the case, then you need to follow the below method.

I am reporting the product with the max quantity.

```
select {[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]} on 0,
non empty
([Product].[Product].[Product],[Promotion].[Max Quantity].[Max Quantity]) on 1 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Now lets manipulate the max quantity to make it behave like a measure.

```
with 
member measures.test
as 
case when [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]>0 then 
(nonempty(([Product].[Product].currentmember,[Promotion].[Max Quantity].[Max Quantity]),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])).item(0).item(1).name
else 
null end

select
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.test}
on 0,
non empty ([Product].[Product].[Product] )
on 1 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]

Now you can use the filter, but we need to cast(note the use of CInt) the data too

```
with 
member measures.test
as 
case when [Measures].[Internet Sales Amount]>0 then 
Cint((nonempty(([Product].[Product].currentmember,[Promotion].[Max Quantity].[Max Quantity]),[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount])).item(0).item(1).name)
else 
null end

select
{[Measures].[Internet Sales Amount],measures.test}
on 0,
non empty (
filter(
[Product].[Product].[Product]
,measures.test>0) 
)
on 1 
from [Adventure Works]
```

[image]