# MDX Query : Add filters in mdx query

Tags: mdx, mdx-query

i am new to writing.mdx queries. Trying to add below conditions

Need help in

- pop2019 larger than 5000
- GDPgrowth more than 1

Query for sales of each country:

```
SELECT
{[Measures].[Sales]} ON 0,
{[Dim Company Info].[LOC].ALLMEMBERS} ON 1
FROM [Database]
```

My schema looks like below:
[Schema Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SIJ1o.png)

Answer (score 1):

You basicly want your diemsion attribute members to behave like measure values.
Take a look at the following

[How to implement "greater than" based on dimension value in MDX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65175026/how-to-implement-greater-than-based-on-dimension-value-in-mdx)